# PHP How to Insert Data Input from a Dynamically-Generated Form

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli, dynamically-generated

I need assistance in taking the next step in inserting data entered into a dynamically-generated form. I have looked for a number of days at other similar questions and am still missing a piece.

Here is my HTML form (minus error trapping/validations):

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="recipeaddsubmit.php">
<table id="myTable">
            <tr>
              <td width="10%">Amount</td>
              <td width="10%">Measure</td>
              <td width="35%">Ingredient</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" name="Amt1" id="Amt1" size="1" />
                <input type="text" name="Amt2" id="Amt2" size="1"  />
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                 <select name="Measure" id="Measure">
                   <option>Cup</option>
                   <option>Ounce</option>
                 </select>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                 <input type="text" name="Ing" id="Ing" size="40" />
              </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         <button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert new row</button>
         <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
         </form>
```

Here is the javascript in my header:

```
<script>
function displayResult()
{
    var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='Amt1' id='Amt1' size='1' /> 
    <input type='text' name='Amt2' id='Amt2' size='1'  />";
    cell2.innerHTML="<select name='Measure' id='Measure'> <option>Cup</option> 
    <option>Ounce</option></select>";
    cell3.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='Ing' id='Ing' size='40' />";
}

</script>
```

And here is my attempted/partial mysqli insert statement (checkInput is a self-created validation function I have used before without issue):

```
$amt1 = checkInput($_POST['Amt1']);
$amt2 = checkInput($_POST['Amt2']);
$measure = checkInput($_POST['Measure']);
$ing = checkInput($_POST['Ing']);

$ingAddQuery ="INSERT INTO Ingredient (Amt1, Amt2, Measure, Ing)
VALUES ({$amt1}, {$amt2}, {$measure}, {$ing})";

mysqli_query($mysqli,$ingAddQuery);              

    if (!mysqli_query($mysqli,$ingAddQuery))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

What I don't understand is how to incorporate a foreach loop in terms of how to increment for a certain number of rows; I understand the concept but not the application in this case.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Name your dynamic inputs with [] (i.e. `<input name="Ing[]">`, submit the form and see what you get.

Comment: I only get the latest record when I try this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion.

Why don't u create a hidden input type.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cellCount" value="0" />
```

Each time u insert a new row, change value of this hidden field. This will not show on browser. This hidden element will also get submit when u submit form. this can be retrieved on server by `$_POST["cellCount"]`.

Hope this will help u.

Comment: Pradeep, I like this idea, but how do I change the value when I insert a new row?

Comment: I think you are adding rows by javascript.

Let us assume name and id of input field are cellCount.

<input type="hidden" name="cellCount" value="0" id="cellCount" />

If multiple rows are created at once, than first create rows and take a counter variable. After creating rows, place this code there 
:


var counter = 10;// assumed counter is number of rows you calculated
document.getElementById("cellCount").value = counter;

Hope this helped u.

Answer (score 0):

change the name from amt1 to amt1[] and etcetera...

so

```
<input type="text" name="Amt1[]" id="Amt1[]" size="1" />
```

When you submit the form,

```
$_POST['Amt1']; //is an array
```

will be an array, so you could do

```
$Amt1Array = $_POST['Amt1'];
foreach($Amt1Array => $Amt1){
//do stuff here
}
```

Better yet you can index the array using the js to create names like...

```
<input type="text" name="Amt1[0]" id="Amt1[0]" size="1" />
<input type="text" name="Amt2[0]" id="Amt2[0]" size="1" />

<input type="text" name="Amt1[1]" id="Amt1[1]" size="1" />
<input type="text" name="Amt2[1]" id="Amt2[1]" size="1" />
```

Then in the PHP you could

```
$Amt1Array = $_POST['Amt1'];
$Amt2Array = $_POST['Amt2'];

foreach($Amt1Array as $key => $Amt1Value){
$Amt2Value = $Amt2Array[$key];
//do stuff with rows
}
```

Comment: Paquino, how to I account for the fact that there is more than one field? I would need Amt1[0] to go with Amt2[0], etc.

Comment: @user1713438 I edited the answer as a follow up to your comment